# Wordpress Query Default Order if Meta Values Same?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

If the main query args look like this:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => 'price',
'order' => 'DESC'
```

What orderby does the query use if the meta_key value is the same for multiple results? So, in the above example, if multiple items have the same price, how does the query order those items? Like a sub-orderby... I thought it would be publish date, but it isn't.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you can use multiple orderby values. So you could say `orderby => 'meta_value_num title'` You can read more about that here: [WP_Query Orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Howdy_McGee. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work if you specify a `meta_key`. The examples in the Codex for the fallback `orderby` parameter use only `orderby` and `order` and skip the `meta_value` or `meta_key` arguments. What happens is that `orderby` defaults to `ASC` when you add a fallback to `orderby` if `meta_key` is present.